# Netty IdleStateHandler times out when executor thread is busy

Tags: java, netty, ping

I'm having trouble getting the IdleStateHandler to not time out while sending intervalled "pings" to the server. This happens when an executor thread is busy processing for a long time (for the same channel).

The first step in the pipeline is an IdleStateHandler with a timeout set to 20 seconds.

A few steps later the pipeline is setup with an OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor with a small queue size set to 3 (maxChannelMemorySize).

When the worker thread that is dispatched from the executor is processing for a long time (can take up to 90s) it seems like the IdelStateHandler can only receive 3 messages (messageReceived). Changing the queue size in the executor to 30 will allow 30 messageReceived calls in IdleStateHandler. Then it times out after 20 more seconds. channelIdle is implemented in the GameServerHandler (last step).

I'm pretty new to Netty so chances are that I've not understood something conceptual with the pipeline - my expectation is that messages to always go between the layers. I would expect IdleStateHandle to be called for every incoming message regardless of the queue size of the executor since its added later.

I'm using netty 3.5.8 final.

What am I missing?

```
OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor eventExecutor = new OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(100, 3, 300);
Timer timer = new HashedWheelTimer();
...


pipeline.addLast("idleHandler", new IdleStateHandler(timer, 20, 0, 0));
...
pipeline.addLast("executionHandler", executionHandler);
pipeline.addLast("handler", new GameServerHandler());
```

Answer (score 0):

The ExecutionHandler should not affect the generation of the IdleStateEvents. What you need to understand is that if your "logic" of handling IdleStateEvents is implemented in the GameServerHandler, it will be depend on how busy your ExecutionHandler is (or in more detail the Executor that is used by it).

So my advice would be to put the handling logic for IdleStateEvents in a separate IdleAwareUpstreamHandler implementation and place it in front of the ExecutionHandler so it will be handled by the IO-Thread and not via the ExecutionHandler.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried adding a 'PingHandler' before the executor, but the same behavior appear. It seems like the IO-thread  stays blocked in AbstractNioWroker (244): int selected = SelectorUtil.select(selector); As a work-around I've increased the queue size for now.

Comment: this makes no sense.. is your code by any chance opensource ? I would love to see it..

Comment: No sorry, I could email you relevant parts though. The fault may very well be on my end. A possible way to try to repro it would be to set up a pipeline like I did with executor, put a long sleep in the handler, and make sure IdleStateHandler received more than queue size messages while the the executor thread is asleep in the handler.

Comment: IF you could write a "testcase" that reproduce it please open an issue in the netty issue tracker